# Qt: get snapshot of all visible window running in Xorg?

Tags: qt, x11, xorg

I know how to retrieve snapshot of current window with its `WId` , but how can I find the list of `WId` e.g of all window present on this desktop , so that I could find all the snapshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to just take a snapshot of the root window.

If you need a list of all windows, use `XQueryTree` on the root window. Bear in mind that a partially obscured window will still be obscured on any snapshot.

Comment: Hi, you mind check this question out: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557126/xlib-qt-cant-get-screenshot-of-root-window-ximage-seems-empty`